# MYSQL schema for comment system

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema

I have a basic comment system on an app I'm creating with the following table setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `meet_comment` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `meet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `comment` mediumtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `meet_id` (`meet_id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `meet_comment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`meet_id`) REFERENCES `meet` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `meet_comment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

`meet_id` is a reference to the object the user is commenting on. This works great, although at the moment if a user edits the comment I am just updating the `comment` field.

I want to be able to see comment history if the comment gets edited, what's the best way to go about this? I'm guessing I will need another table that holds the comment and references `meet_comment.id`? Maybe like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `meet_comment` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `meet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `meet_id` (`meet_id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `meet_comment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`meet_id`) REFERENCES `meet` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `meet_comment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `meet_comment_content` (
 `revision` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `meet_comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `comment` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `revision_2` (`revision`,`meet_comment_id`),
 KEY `revision` (`revision`),
 KEY `meet_comment_id` (`meet_comment_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `meet_comment_content` FOREIGN KEY (`meet_comment_id`) REFERENCES `meet_comment` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

If so, what would be the best way to query the tables, I'm guessing I can do a join to get the required data?

Answer (score 3):

Revision history leads to a tug of war --

- Simplicity, or not
- Efficiency at scale, or not
- Complexity of the queries, or not
- Disk space, or bloat

Consider the following "general" principle:

Have two tables:

- `Current` -- the current version of the Comment
- `History` -- all versions of the Comment

`Current` makes the *main* queries simpler and more efficient.

Creating or editing a Comment means an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` in `Current`, plus (always) an `INSERT` into `History`.

`History` will have a *slightly* different schema than `Current`, since there needs to be a revision number, and maybe other dates/flags/etc.

This does not address disk space; I suspect you can last some time before needing to worry about such.  One technique is to "compress" the main `TEXT` column and put it into a `BLOB`.  (Note: another schema difference.  And added complexity in the code.)  Typical text shrinks by 3:1.

Side note:  `int(3)` -- the `(3)` says nothing.  An `INT` is always 4 bytes.  Suggest using `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`, which takes 2 bytes and has a range of 0..64K.

I would abandon the `FOREIGN KEYs`, especially the `CASCADE`; there are likely to be references that will get tangled up in these two tables.  Anyway, you will need to carefully write the code to handle the various tasks, thereby obviating the need for FKs.

Every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  For "clustering" of data, I recommend `(comment_id, revision)`, not the other way around.

And, consider whether `meet_id` be part of the PK.

Answer (score 3):

```
-- User USR exists.
--
user {USR}
  PK {USR}
```

```
-- Meet MET exists.
--
meet {MET}
  PK {MET}
```

```
-- User USR attended meet MET.
--
user_meet {USR, MET}
       PK {USR, MET}

FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user {USR}
FK2 {MET} REFERENCES meet {MET}
```

*If a user commented on a meet, then that user attended that meet.*

```
-- User USR commented CMT_TXT on meet MET,
-- as comment number CMT_NO from that user on that meet.
--
comment {USR, MET, CMT_NO, CMT_TXT}
     PK {USR, MET, CMT_NO}

FK {USR, MET} REFERENCES user_meet {USR, MET}

-- For any given (USR, MET), CMT_NO is in {1,2,3 ...}.
```

```
-- User USR commented CMT_TXT on meet MET,
-- in version number VER_NO of comment number CMT_NO
-- from that user on that meet.
--
comment_history {USR, MET, CMT_NO, VER_NO, CMT_TXT}
             PK {USR, MET, CMT_NO, VER_NO}

     FK {USR, MET, CMT_NO} REFERENCES
comment {USR, MET, CMT_NO}
     ON UPDATE CASCADE
     ON DELETE RESTRICT

-- For any given (USR, MET, CMT_NO), VER_NO is in {1,2,3 ...}.
```

I would suggest to treat deletion of a comment as a new version. You may, for example, set `comment.CMT_TXT` to an empty string. This way the history and data integrity are both preserved.

If `comment_history` contains only older versions, and the current is in `comment`, then use a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_comment
AS
SELECT USR
     , MET
     , CMT_NO
     , 'current' as VER
     , CMT_TXT
FROM comment
UNION
SELECT USR
     , MET
     , CMT_NO
     , concat('ver_', lpad(VER_NO,3,0)) as VER
     , CMT_TXT
FROM comment_history ;
```

To query comments and histories for a specific user and meet:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM v_comment
WHERE USR = specific_user
  AND MET = specific_meet
ORDER BY CMT_NO, VER
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go with too many complex queries and implements, you can go with simple implementation.

Like JOINs

```sql
SELECT
  mc.id,
  mc.meet_id as meet_id,
  mc.user_id as user_id,
  mcc.revision as revision,
  mcc.date_created as date_created,
  mcc.comment as comment
FROM
  meet_comment as mc
LEFT JOIN
  meet_comment_content as mcc
ON
  mc.meet_id = mcc.meet_id
```

This query will give you the entire comment histories.

If you want comments from some particular user, then you have to add it in where

```sql
WHERE
    mc.user_id = <User Id>
```

If you just want comments from a particular meet ID and User, you can add it in `WHERE` clause.

```sql
WHERE
    mc.meet_id = <Meet ID> AND
    mc.user_id = <User ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

Few pointers while designing a database-

1. Logically segregating data is the best approach while designing a database. For example- The `comment` table should only have comments and no info about meet or user.
2. There should be separate mapping tables for mappings. This will give you the flexibility you need. So if in future, let's you want to add a feature of commenting on a comment(nested comments) like Reddit, you can do that with ease by introducing an additional column of `parent_comment_id` in the master `comment` table.

IMO there should be the following tables-

1. `user`- `user_id`, and other user-related fields
2. `meet`- `meet_id` and other meet-related fields
3. `comment`- `comment_id`, `revision_id`, and other comment-related fields like
4. `user_meet_mapping`- `user_id`, `meet_id` etc.
5. `meet_comment_mapping`- `meet_id`, `comment_id` etc.

This schema is the best normalization one can achieve. As far as your queries are concerned, you can extract them by various paginated join queries.

Comment: "This schema is the best normalization one can achieve." Really? So a comment can exists out of context of user and meet? Normalization does not *introduce* logical errors, it removes and prevents them.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic Are you recommending that an entity like comment should always be bound with another parent entity like user or post or meeting? I understand your POV about entities existing out of context. However, I don't completely agree that it's a logical error. With the application layer maintaining data integrity, it should not be a problem. I would also appreciate it if you could point me some resources for reference about better schema designs.

Comment: In this example, a comment can be created out of of "thin air" (maybe by a user) related to nothing. Maybe, or maybe not, later you enter it into your `meet_comment_mapping`; certainly you can delete it and leave it dangling. DB *normalization* "...the best ..." does not include an application level.